# When pressing the OK Button for my EXcel VBA Form the info does not get added to the data table correctly

Tags: excel, vba, forms, format, spreadsheet

I am trying to format an 'Ok' button so that all the information in my form fills in the next empty row in my data table.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer Information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = BoatModelComboBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = BoatIDTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = NameofDefectComboBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = InspectionAreaComboBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = DateTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = OccurenceTextBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = DefectOriginComboBox.Value

If BoatCheckOptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = "TRUE"
Else
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = "FALSE"
End If

If TireKickOptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = "TRUE"
Else
    Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = "FALSE"
End If

Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = TypeofInspectionComboBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = MonthComboBox.Value
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: why's this not doing what you want?

Comment: please tell us the problem here... I assume that braX got the right answer, but this needs to be verified. (-1 & vtc)

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the empty row like this instead

```
emptyRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```